# Postgresql group transactions by category with a column for each month

Tags: postgresql

Here is the schema I'm working with

```
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date date,
    amount double precision,
    category character varying,
    full_category character varying,
    transaction_id character varying,
    created_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX transactions_pkey ON transactions(id int8_ops);
```

I would like to group the data with the following columns:

Category, January Total, February Total, March Total, and so on for every month.

This is as far as I've got:

```
SELECT 
    category, sum(amount) as january_total
from transactions 
where category NOT IN ('Transfer', 'Payment', 'Deposit', 'Income')
AND date >= '2021-01-01' AND date < '2021-02-01' 
group by category
Order by january_total asc
```

How do I add a column for every month to this output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
SELECT 
    category, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN date >= '2021-01-01' AND date <'2021-02-01' THEN amount ELSE 0.00 END) AS january,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date >= '2021-02-01' AND date <'2021-03-01' THEN amount ELSE 0.00 END) AS february,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date >= '2021-03-01' AND date <'2021-04-01' THEN amount ELSE 0.00 END) AS march,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date >= '2021-04-01' AND date <'2021-05-01' THEN amount ELSE 0.00 END) AS april
from transactions
where category NOT IN ('Transfer', 'Payment', 'Deposit', 'Income')
GROUP BY category
Order by category
```

Comment: You can shorten the above by replacing date comparisons with the extract function. Instead of   "date >= '2021-01-01' AND date <'2021-02-01'" just use  "extract( month from date)::int".

Comment: I would caution against using DATE as a column (or variable even) name. It is not only a data type but also a [SQL reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and *they are never allowed as identifiers*. While Postgres does not currently enforce this, future versions could thus invalidating your ddl and code.